# Jquery.min.js and AdminLte apps.js corrupted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with the Jquery.min.js where i need it to have my nested checkbox worked. I'm currently using AdminLte theme, when i try to replace the jquery refence in the adminLTe theme , my checkbox only work if i put the reference like this :

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="js/AdminLTE/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="js/AdminLTE/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.deepcheckbox.js"></script>
```

But if i put like that my adminLte sidebar is not working anymore, i figure it out the problem is that if the js/AdminLte/app.js is on top of the jquery.min.js then my adminLTE sidebar is working fine but my nested checkbox won't work.

What is the problem that occur in the reference? Is there some corruption? or anything i can do to let both sidebar and nested checkbox work? Thanks

Edit:
I get this error on the javascript console on app.js line 65 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
 * ADD SLIMSCROLL TO THE TOP NAV DROPDOWNS
 * ---------------------------------------
 */
$(".navbar .menu").slimscroll({
    height: "200px",
    alwaysVisible: false,
    size: "3px"
}).css("width", "100%");
```

Comment: Probably there is conflict between `app.js` and your `deepcheckbox.js`. Check what is happening using browser console.

Comment: I had check the deepcheckbox.js it seem like it is fine. I suspect he jquery.min.js is conflict with app.js

Comment: thats the problem here too. If I include this file, jquery goes down